# Delaying a mouseover

Tags: javascript

Sorry, I know this question has been asked and answered but I can't get this to work. Can anyone tell me why the mouseover on the first text box in the first row of the table in this fiddle does not work?

```
<table style="width:280px; border:1px solid Red;">
<tr>
<td>Label</td>
<td><input id="txt1" type="text" onclick="showdiv('txt1')" value="fred" 
onmouseover="function() { funcDelay=window.setTimeout('jim()', 1000); }">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**[FIDDLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/GNUes/8/)**

Answer (score 0):

Because you're confusing the two methods of setting events. The attribute should be set to an statement string, not a function string.

```
onmouseover="funcDelay=window.setTimeout('jim()', 1000);
```

Also, you can replace `'jim()'` (a string to be executed) with a function reference: `jim`

Answer (score 0):

Use :

**html**

```
<input id="txt1" type="text" onclick="showdiv('txt1')" value="fred" onmouseover="jim2()">
```

**js**

```
function jim2() { funcDelay=window.setTimeout('jim()', 1000); }
```

And it'll work. because the inline events take statement(s) as input not methods.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the the setTimeOut within the function:-

```
<td>Label</td><td><input id="txt1" type="text" onclick="showdiv('txt1')" value="fred" 
onmouseover='jim()'></td>

function jim()
{
window.setTimeout( function(){alert('jimmy')}, 1000); 

}
```